# What are the main differences between metastable and virtual intermediate states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

I'm studying energy transfer and upconversion processes. The process of ground state absorption followed by excited state absorption involves a metastable intermediate state, whereas a process of two-photon absorption involves a virtual intermediate state. I understand the general concept of both types of processes, however, I want to have a clear picture of metastable and virtual states.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual state is the result of an externally applied field. Take away the field, there's no virtual state. But a metastable state persists even if the field that excited it is removed.

Comment: Thanks! I consider your answer helpful, and indeed it makes sense. Thx